# How can I efficiently find subsets of a set in a map?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Consider that I have a map of sets of values to values, in Java the type of this map would be:

```
Map<Set<Object>, Object> setToObjMap;
```

Given a new set of objects `set`, I wish to find all values in the setToObjMap where the associated key is a **subset** of a "search set".

So, for example, if my map was:

```
["telephone", "hat"] -> "book"
["laugh", "fry", "mouse"] -> "house"
["dog", "cat"] -> "monster"
```

Then, given the search set `["telephone", "hat", "book", "dog", "cat"]` I would retrieve the values "book" and "monster".

In practice there may be tens of thousands of entries in the `setToObjectMap`, with tens of thousands of possible values in the sets.  The search set will typically have around 10 elements.

I'm hoping there is an efficient way to do this that doesn't require iterating through all keys in the map.  Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Comment: The question is moot unless you have implemented `Map` and `Set` yourself and thus have access to their internals. Any reasonable stock implementation would not provide a public interface that allows solutions other than the obvious.

Comment: Yes, obviously I'm asking how I implement the datastructure, hence the "data-structure" tag on the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a lookup data structure

```
Map<String,List<Finder>>
```

With `Finder` having an int `count` and `max`, and a `res` word. Take note that the list is there to take care of the case where many sets in `setToObjMap` can share the same word, which is not in your examples.

```
"telephone" -> [{res:"book",count=0,max=2}]
"hat" -> same object as above
"laugh" -> [{res:"house",count=0,max=3}]
...
```

This lookup collection is quick to build and even quicker to flush after a lookup.

The lookup algorithm iterates through `set`, for each word, and each Finder for this word, it increases the `count` variable. Second pass, take all values of the lookup map, if `count==max`, put `res` in the result.

Init algorithm:

```
for Entry e in setToObjMap
  Finder f = new Finder(e.value, 0, e.key.size) // res, count, max
  for String word in e.key
    lookup.get(word).add(f)
```

Lookup algorithm:

```
for String word in set
  for Finder f in lookup.get(word)
    f.count ++
for Finder f in lookup.values()
  if (f.count==f.max)
    res.add(f.res)
```

Reset algorithm:

```
for Finder f in lookup.values()
    f.count = 0
```

As for the complexity, if n is the number of elements in `set` and m the number of values in `setToObjMap`, the complexity will be O(n+m)

Comment: This looks interesting, but after staring at it for a few minutes I'm having trouble understanding it - can you flesh it out a bit?  For example, what exactly is the "lookup count"?  What part of this algorithm is pre-computed?  Do you know what the time complexity of this is?

Comment: Just edited my answer with algorithm pseudo-code and complexity.

Comment: Hmm, but isn't the naive solution, which is to iterate through the map, better than this, given that it has O(m) complexity?

Comment: O(m) for iterating through the Map, yes, but then for each Map item, you need to check that the set is a subset of `set`, which is a O(n) complexity with n the average size of sets.  The total is O(n*m) which is far worse.

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over the map is one option. This takes O(*n* × *m*) time, where *n* is the number of entries in the map and *m* is the number of items in the query set; the *m* factor comes about because of the subset check.

The other option is generating [all subsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of the set to search for and looking those up in the map. That takes O(2^*m*) time. That may be faster than the first option if 2^*m* is small compared to *n* (so *m* should be very small). In your example use case, 2^*m* = 2^10 = 1024, which is less than tens of thousands.

If the query set size is known to vary, you can even use a hybrid strategy: compute the number 2^*m* and check whether it is smaller than *n*, then select the best of these two options depending on the result of the check.

Comment: Per your first suggestion, I'm hoping there is something better than the "obvious" solution of iterating through the entire map.  Your second suggestion is interesting, but I'll hang on to see if there is anything better than O(2^m).

Comment: The subset check of the first solution is not obvious, its complexity is O(n) with n being the average size of subsets, so the first solution has a O(n*m) complexity.

Comment: @solendil: true, I'll add that to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the sets in question are small, and the map is large, the best way would be to generate all subsets of the set and look those up in the map.

If your set has `k` elements and there are `n` associations in the map, that would take `2^k` lookups vs. `n` subset checks the other way round. You see that for `n = 1000` and `k = 20` that would be a bad idea, but for `n = 100000` and `k = 10`, it would be a win.

Comment: Yes, this is an interesting suggestion (although I think @larsmans beat you to it).  I think I'll hold out for other suggestions.

Comment: fair enough, submission time alone isn't the sole criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option is to build an index from single element to the key sets:

```
"hat" -> ["telephone", "hat"]
"telephone" -> ["telephone", "hat"]
"laugh"->["laugh", "fry", "mouse"]
"fry"->["laugh", "fry", "mouse"]
"mouse"->["laugh", "fry", "mouse"]
"dog" -> ["dog", "cat"]
"cat" -> ["dog", "cat"]
```

It will allow quickly query key sets by input.

Answer (score 0):

If the members of your sets are subjet to some ordering, then you could hold them in a tree structure, and attach the key-value mappings at the leaves. Then, when you follow the path of a subset down the tree, all leaves under that subtree will be sets containing your subset.