# Best way to find a subset of a set from a group of sets

Tags: c++, algorithm, set, subset

First, sorry for the ambiguous title.

Assume I have the following group of sets:

#### Group 1

```
s1 = ( x1, y1 )
s2 = ( x2 )
```

#### Group 2

```
m1 = ( x1, y1, y2 )
m2 = ( x1 )
m3 = ( x1 , x2 )
```

For each of the sets in `Group 1` - call the set `s`, I need to find the sets in `Group 2` - call it `m` - such that `m` is a subset of `s`.

So, for my example, the answer would be:

```
s1 -> m2
s2 -> nothing
```

For now, I'm storing the values in `std:set`, but I can change that if needed. Also, the sets can get big, so the algorithm needs to be efficient. For now I have a brute-force approach, which I'm not entirely satisfied with.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So, in your example, it should only return m2, which is a subset of s1?

Comment: @crush yes, I already posted the solution for my example.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you saying that m1 is a subset of s1, or the other way around? It seems s1 is a subset of m1. But then s2 is a subset of m3, so wouldn't you have s2 -> m3? Sorry if I'm misunderstanding this.

Comment: @Patrick87 I'm sorry, my mistake. It should be m2, not m1. Corrected.

Comment: Can you use a sorted list and use a binary search?

Comment: @crush I can choose a different data structure, yes, but I'm not sure what you mean. Sort what by what?

Comment: @Mr.Anubis I can't use external libs. And not necesarilly a subset algorithm. I can store the data in a different format. Whatever is fastest.

Comment: Have you considered vector of unordered_set? , that way you can implement subset (Which I think it's most expensive in whole operation) efficiently even using your bruteforce technique. I mostly find myself wrong , so ignore my comment if you do too :|

Comment: @Mr.Anubis it doesn't sound bad. I chose to use set because the values are unique per set. But I'm looking for a tested algorithm or approach. Maybe even with restructuring of data. If you have any ideas, post an answer.

Comment: Very similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8504666/1009831)

Comment: Do you have a list of unique elements that could appear in your sets? It it bounded?

Comment: Here is something interesting I found : http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7466/finding-a-subset-of-a-set-in-a-collection-of-sets

Answer (score 1):

The first step would be to sort Group 1 according to cardinality (i.e. size).  Then the algorithm is something on the order of:

```
foreach std::set M in "Group 2" {
  foreach std::set S in "Group 1" and S.size()>=M.size() {  // replace with binary search
     if ( std::includes(S.begin(),S.end(),M.begin(),M.end()) )
       { /* M is a subset of S */ }
    }
  }
}
```

This should have time complexity ~O(MSR), where M is the # of sets in "Group 2", S the # of sets in "Group 1", and R is the size of largest set in "Group #1".

**Edit:**  It just occurred to me that it might be more efficient to use `S.find()` rather than calling `std::includes()` (which iterates sequentially) but I think that would only be true if M.size() is much smaller than S.size() -- O(M+S) vs O(MlogS).

Comment: If you're going to down-vote me, that's fine but at least give some rationale for doing so.  Is what I wrote wrong?

Comment: Hmm... we are afflicted by a serial drive-by downvoter here. Some people just refuse to play nice :|

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic:  I answered a question once that had that happen as well.  Most of the answers were downvoted with no explanation ... twice.  Seems a bit strange, but most people play this "game" fairly well.  It's a good community.

Answer (score 0):

You are not specific about how brute-force your approach is.  As long as you are using the set  query functions in the std:: namespace then they are likely to be as efficient as they can be.
For example testing if set_intersection( s1.begin(), s2.end(), m1.begin(), m1.end() ) is equivalent to m1.

You could be more efficient than this, as you do not want a copy of the matching elements, just to know they all appear.  This could be done by copying the code of set_intersection but changing the implementation to simply count the number of matching elements rather than copying them out.  Then if the count is the same as the size of m then you have a match.

As for containers, I often prefer a sorted deque over a set for large collections.  The memory is much less distributed over the heap which helps with caching.  It also avoids the overhead of the underlying tree.  This is especially beneficial when the containers are created once, but are searched multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Are your sets frequently modified or are they read-only/mostly?

- If frequently modified, `std::set` is a fine balance between modification and sort performance.
- If read-only or read-mostly, you can use a sorted `std::vector`. Sorting is expensive, but is actually cheaper than constructing a whole tree in the `std::set`, so performance is better if you do it rarely enough.

Once you have made the sorted containers (be it "auto-sorted" `std::set` or manually-sorted `std::vector`), you can test for subset using `std::includes`. BTW, if you need to find *proper* subsets, you can compare element counts afterwards.

Comment: I didn't know std::includes() even existed.  I think I need to modify my response now...

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. 
Steps:

- create an array that contains all objects in both group
- convert every s and m in a bit array, where array(i)=1 if the set contains object(i), 0 otherwise
- m(k) is a subset of s(j) if m(k) AND s(j) = m(k)